# Bash Looping through directories and filenames

Tags: bash, for-loop, directory

I need to loop through various directories and filenames having the same name, but incrementing by 1, from 001, 002, 003 to 100.

```
/Very/long/path/to/folder001/very_long_filename001.foobar
/Very/long/path/to/folder002/very_long_filename002.foobar
/Very/long/path/to/folder003/very_long_filename003.foobar


$FILES=/Very/long/path/to/folder*/very_long_filename*.foobar
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "$f"
done
```

The `for` loop I wrote above doesn't work, and I really don't understand why ! Any hint ?Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an array instead:

```
FILES=(/Very/long/path/to/folder*/very_long_filename*.foobar)
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  echo "$f"
done
```

Another way to make it run in order:

```
for i in $(seq -w 001 100); do
    f="/Very/long/path/to/folder${i}/very_long_filename${i}.foobar"
    [[ -e $f ]] || continue  ## optional test.
    echo "$f"
done
```

By the way your `for` loop doesn't work since you started your assignment with `$`:

```
`$FILES=...`
```

It should simply have been

```
FILES=/Very/long/path/to/folder*/very_long_filename*.foobar
```

Still using an array is safer since it preserves spaces within filenames during expansion for `for`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I come from Perl, hence the $FILES :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use a dollar sign to assign to a variable:

```
FILES=/Very/long/path/to/folder*/very_long_filename*.foobar
```

You don't need a variable at all; you can iterate directly over a glob pattern:

```
for f in /Very/long/path/to/folder*/very_long_filename*.foobar; do
```